# Show image on the sharing dialog while sending it by intent ACTION_SEND when SDK_INT < Q

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

i want to show image on the sharing dialog (when i use ACTION_SEND  intent), every thing go right when SDK_INT >= Q, but not with SDK_INT < Q.

in my code, i create a provider and add it to the manifests, create a function to save a bitmap as PNG and return its URI, and at last i am passing this URI to the intent..

but the image doesn't appear on the dialog.

this is how it looks like with SDK >= Q, and that how i wantt it to look like with sdk < Q:

[image: how it looks with SDK >= Q]

manifests:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Provider:

```
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

creating the URI funtion:

```
 fun Bitmap.saveAsPng(context: Context, filename: String) = "$filename.png".let { name ->
        if (SDK_INT < Q) {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PICTURES), name)
            FileOutputStream(file).use { compress(PNG, 100, it) }
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                context,
                arrayOf(file.absolutePath), null, null
            )
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                "${context.packageName}.provider", file
            )
        } else {
            val values = ContentValues().apply {
                put(DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                put(MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
                put(RELATIVE_PATH, DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                put(IS_PENDING, 1)
            }

            val resolver = context.contentResolver
            val uri = resolver.insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
                ?.use { compress(PNG, 100, it) }

            values.clear()
            values.put(IS_PENDING, 0)
            uri?.also {
                resolver.update(it, values, null, null)
            }
        }
    }
```

and at last call intent:

```
val uriString = bitmap.saveAsPng(context, "qrcodeImg")
                    uriString?.let { uri ->
                        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                            type = "image/*"
                            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri)
                            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                        }
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via..."))
                    }
```